# Remotely create a vhost on a docker container running rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, docker, vagrantfile

I have a Vagrantfile that does 2 important things; firstly pulls and runs dockerfile/rabbitmq, then builds from a custom Dockerfile that runs an application which assumes a vhost on the rabbitmq server, let's say "/foo".

The problem is the vhost is not there.

The container with rabbitmq is running successfully, the app is linked to it using --link as the built image is run. Using the environment variables docker sets I can hit the server. But somewhere in the middle of these operations I need to create the vhost as my connection is refused, i assume because "/foo" is not there.

How can I get the vhost onto the rabbit server?

Thanks

note - using the webadmin is not an option, this has to be done programatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put `default_vhost` in `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config`: http://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html

It will then be created on the first run. (Stop and delete the mnesia directory if has been started already)

Comment: This doesn't explain how to do it in the docker...

Comment: @acidjunk for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266688/how-to-create-a-queue-in-rabbitmq-upon-startup

Answer (score 4):

There are few ways to get desired configuration:

- Export/import whole configuration with [`rabbitmqadmin` - Management Plugin CLI tool](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management-cli.html).

or

- Use [HTTP API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/rabbitmq_v3_3_5/priv/www/api/index.html) from [management plugin](http://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html)

or

- Use [`rabbitmqctl` cli tool](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html#idp17615552) to manage access control.

Comment: Thanks Zaq. I've had difficulties with these options. Even installing the management plugin on linux! It feels like i should just be able to use `rabbitmqctl` and add the vhost passing a host option, but maybe i've got the syntax wrong. However, having my vhosts in config also sounds like a good option. Can you give some examples?

Comment: There are example on the `rabbitmqctl` manual page (i fixed the link in the answer). As to `rabbitmqadmin`, the idea is to manually configure rabbitmq server and then export it configuration to reuse later. There are also cli examples on the `rabbitmqadmin` link (at the bottom of the page).

Answer (score 0):

BTW according to docs in here: https://www.rabbitmq.com/vhosts.html
You can du this via curl by using:

```
curl -u userename:pa$sw0rD -X PUT http://rabbitmq.local:15672/api/vhosts/vh1
```

So probably it doesnt matter you are doing this remotely or not..