# How to create a queue in RabbitMQ upon startup

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to start RMQ inside docker container, with precreated queue `qwer`.

Prior to this, I was using simple `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:management-alpine
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
```

And it worked fine, except that it has no queues pre-created at start.
Now I've switched to custom image, with following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM rabbitmq:management-alpine

ADD rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/
ADD definitions.json /etc/rabbitmq/

RUN chown rabbitmq:rabbitmq /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
```

where `rabbitmq.conf` is v3.7+ sysctl-styled config, with line:

```
management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
```

and `definitions.json` contains attempt to create queue:

```
{
    "vhosts":[
        {"name":"/"}
    ],
    "queues":[
        {"name":"qwer","vhost":"/","durable":true,"auto_delete":false,"arguments":{}}
    ]
}
```

Now it started to refuse login:

```
Error on AMQP connection <0.660.0> (172.18.0.6:48916 -> 172.18.0.10:5672, state: starting):
PLAIN login refused: user 'guest' - invalid credentials
```

I thought that the task is somewhat simple, but configuration process of rabbit itself is most complex task, and documentation is somewhat unclear.

I was unable to figure out how should it work, even after 4 days of trials and googling..

Could you help me, how to write configuration file, in order to create a queue and preserve ability to connect and talk to it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are almost there actually.

RabbitMQ has a rule that the "guest" user can only connect from localhost. Since you are running it on a docker, I'm assuming you are trying to access it from outside by exposing port "15672" by doing: `docker run <rabbitmq-docker-img> -p 15672:15672`

So to get around this, what you have to do is create a user with admin privileges.

Firstly, change this:

```
rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:management-alpine
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: user
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: password
```

You can use ath, I used user/password as your user/password.

In your Dockerfile, you can add: `EXPOSE 15672` If you don't want to expose each time you run.

Lastly, make amends to your definitions.json file as follows:

```
{
    "users": [
      {
        "name": "user",  
        "password_hash": "password",
        "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
        "tags": "administrator"
      }
    ],

    "vhosts":[
        {"name":"/"}
    ],
    "queues":[
        {"name":"qwer","vhost":"/","durable":true,"auto_delete":false,"arguments":{}}
    ]
}
```

Let me know how it goes!

Check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30747469/how-to-add-initial-users-when-starting-a-rabbitmq-docker-container)

Use this Dockerfile:

```
FROM rabbitmq

# Define environment variables.
ENV RABBITMQ_USER user
ENV RABBITMQ_PASSWORD password

ADD init.sh /init.sh
EXPOSE 15672

# Define default command
CMD ["/init.sh"]
```

And use this init.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Create Rabbitmq user
( sleep 5 ; \
rabbitmqctl add_user $RABBITMQ_USER $RABBITMQ_PASSWORD 2>/dev/null ; \
rabbitmqctl set_user_tags $RABBITMQ_USER administrator ; \
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / $RABBITMQ_USER  ".*" ".*" ".*" ; \
echo "*** User '$RABBITMQ_USER' with password '$RABBITMQ_PASSWORD' completed. ***" ; \
echo "*** Log in the WebUI at port 15672 (example: http:/localhost:15672) ***") &

# $@ is used to pass arguments to the rabbitmq-server command.
# For example if you use it like this: docker run -d rabbitmq arg1 arg2,
# it will be as you run in the container rabbitmq-server arg1 arg2
rabbitmq-server $@
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input. It crashes on `[info] <0.270.0> Importing users...
CRASH REPORT Process <0.269.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: {error,<<"{not_base64,<<\"guest\">>}">>} in application_master:init/4 line 138
[info] <0.43.0> Application rabbit exited with reason: {error,<<"{not_base64,<<\"guest\">>}">>}`

Comment: I've renamed `user` `password` to `guest` `guest`, because all stack is configured to use that credentials

Comment: Connection is done with endpoint: `amqp://guest:guest@rabbit:5672/`

Comment: Changed `password_hash` to `password` , added `loopback_users = none`. Now another problem arised: `access to vhost '/' refused for user 'guest'`

Comment: can you please post your entire Dockerfile? 

You cannot use "guest" because guest is only allowed access on localhost.

Comment: Editted my answer, have a look at that link .You need to add "user" to vhost "/"

Comment: Your Dockerfile isn't actually leveraging your `rabbitmq.conf` or `definitions.json` files. You can see this in the logs when running the image, it uses the default:
`Successfully set user tags for user 'guest' to [administrator]`.

You need to add to your Dockerfile
`COPY rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq` and `COPY definitions.json /etc/rabbitmq`

Although you don't need to create a user in `definitions.json` and in your `init.sh`, so you can omit the json file.

Answer (score 27):

You can predefine queues and exchanges without creating own rabbit-mq docker image.

Your docker-compose should look like this:

```
rabbit:
container_name: rabbitmq-preload-conf
image: rabbitmq:3-management
volumes:
  - ./init/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:ro
  - ./init/definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json:ro
ports:
  - "5672:5672"
  - "15672:15672"
```

In this case rabbitmq.conf and definitions.json files should be in init folder in the same parent folder as docker-compose file

rabbitmq.conf file

```
management.load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
```

definitions.json file

```
{
"queues": [
    {
        "name": "externally_configured_queue",
        "vhost": "/",
        "durable": true,
        "auto_delete": false,
        "arguments": {
            "x-queue-type": "classic"
        }
    }
],
"exchanges": [
    {
        "name": "externally_configured_exchange",
        "vhost": "/",
        "type": "direct",
        "durable": true,
        "auto_delete": false,
        "internal": false,
        "arguments": {}
    }
],
"bindings": [
    {
        "source": "externally_configured_exchange",
        "vhost": "/",
        "destination": "externally_configured_queue",
        "destination_type": "queue",
        "routing_key": "externally_configured_queue",
        "arguments": {}
    }
  ]
 }
```

**NOTE**: After update in rabbit images, additional configuration may be required. If rabbit container failed to start with the configuration mentioned above (error message contains "**Exception during startup:
exit:{error,{no_such_vhost,<<"/">>}}"**) following configuration should be added into definitions file:

```
 "users": [
    {
      "name": "guest",
      "password_hash": "BMfxN8drrYcIqXZMr+pWTpDT0nMcOagMduLX0bjr4jwud/pN",
      "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
      "tags": [
        "administrator"
      ],
      "limits": {}
    }
  ],
  "vhosts": [
    {
      "name": "/"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    {
      "user": "guest",
      "vhost": "/",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
    }
  ]
```

Using this additional configuration, default user will be guest with password guest.

Apart from queues, exchanges and bindings, definitions.json file can contain additional configuration

Answer (score 6):

I found the accepted answers use of `init.sh` and committing the password unencrypted in the `definitions.json` file to be insufficient for my needs, and came up with the following solution instead:

Start with a vanilla RabbitMQ, configure its queues and users through the web UI, export the configuration and then copy it into a new docker image (or you could mount it into the base RabbitMQ image of your choice as a volume, if you prefer):

1. Start a container running the `rabbitmq:3.9-management` image and publish the admin interface port to the localhost:

```
docker run -p 8080:15672 rabbitmq:3.9-management
```

1. Visit http://localhost:8080 in a browser and login with username: **guest**, password: **guest**.
2. Configure and create the queue(s) in the RabbitMQ web UI under the *Queues* tab. Also create any additional users you might want.
3. Export the definitions under the *Overview* tab. Name the file `definitions.json` and place it in an empty directory `conf`:

```
$ tree .
.
└── conf
    └── definitions.json
```

4. Create a file, `rabbitmq.conf`, containing the single line:

```
load_definitions = /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
```

and place it in the `conf` directory:

```
$ tree .
.
└── conf
    ├── definitions.json
    └── rabbitmq.conf
```

5. Define a new docker image with the RabbitMQ definitions copied into it:

```
FROM rabbitmq:3.9-management
COPY conf/rabbitmq.conf /etc/rabbitmq/
COPY conf/definitions.json /etc/rabbitmq/
```

and a `docker-compose.yml` file to build the image and run the container:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  my-rabbitmq:
    build: .
    ports:
    - 8082:15672
```

Directory structure:

```
$ tree .
.
├── Dockerfile
├── conf
│   ├── definitions.json
│   └── rabbitmq.conf
└── docker-compose.yml
```

1. Start the container:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build
```

and visit the web UI to ensure the definitions have been loaded and the queue created.

---

If you don't want to configure your RabbitMQ through the UI, the `definitions.json` file is pretty self-explanatory, so it should be straight forward to edit it in order to add new queus, creating new users etc., though you need to [see the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306350/how-to-generate-password-hash-for-rabbitmq-management-http-api) on how to create the sha256 hash.