# Docker compose rabbitmq create qeueue on startup

Tags: docker-compose, rabbitmq

I am trying to setup docker compose with 3 services: 1 rabbitmq service and 2 java applications(1 producer and 1 consumer). When rabbitmq service starts, it has no queues by default. Only when produces send message to queue it actually creates it. In the same time, consumer requires queue which it has listen to. So here is the problem: when i run my docker compose, rabbitmq starts fine with my producer, but consumer can't find queue and fails. So, can i somehow set-up docker compose rabbitmq service to start and create queue by default?

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: help
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: 51243
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
```

@Update
I found pretty good way to achieve what i want. I can start rabbitmq, create all what i need(queue) and export definitions.json. Then i need put it under /etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:management
    container_name: rabbitmq
    restart: always
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: ete
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: 1402
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - ./definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/definitions.json
```

But here is another problem: this definition file overrides my user that i set by environment variables.
Here is definition.json:

```
{
  "rabbit_version": "3.8.9",
  "rabbitmq_version": "3.8.9",
  "product_name": "RabbitMQ",
  "product_version": "3.8.9",
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "eternal",
      "password_hash": "wz1jzbGjNMZ115U7XhEUvF271uImnOfho2jpx2pOvLSY/Ssl",
      "hashing_algorithm": "rabbit_password_hashing_sha256",
      "tags": "administrator"
    }
  ],
  "vhosts": [
    {
      "name": "/"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    {
      "user": "eternal",
      "vhost": "/",
      "configure": ".*",
      "write": ".*",
      "read": ".*"
    }
  ],
  "topic_permissions": [],
  "parameters": [],
  "global_parameters": [
    {
      "name": "cluster_name",
      "value": "rabbit@58cb492cd4ee"
    },
    {
      "name": "internal_cluster_id",
      "value": "rabbitmq-cluster-id-DlZ_FZVpiFx93CVZXneG4A"
    }
  ],
  "policies": [],
  "queues": [
    {
      "name": "qqq",
      "vhost": "/",
      "durable": false,
      "auto_delete": false,
      "arguments": {}
    }
  ],
  "exchanges": [],
  "bindings": []
}
```

If i will remove users section and everything else and keep only queue section, then after docker-compose up, i can't log in into managment page. Because my login and password is not accepted.

Comment: You may check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266688/how-to-create-a-queue-in-rabbitmq-upon-startup), perhaps it will help :)

Comment: @NPinheiro i've already seen all those questions and they all seems kind of not what i want. Answer suggests to create another docker image extended from rabbitmq. I actually wanna solve it only inside docker-compose