How can I ADD a virtual host to a rabbitmq I have set up in a docker-compose file?
I want to add another Virtual Host to the rabbitmq I have set up as this:

rabbitmq:
image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
container_name: 'rabbitmq'
volumes:
- ./DockerFiles/rabbitmq/data/:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
- ./DockerFiles/rabbitmq/log/:/var/log/rabbitmq
- ./DockerFiles/rabbitmq/plugins.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins
networks:
rabbitmq_go_net

I guess that I should create it similar to the way I have set up the plugins I want to have, maybe having this volume:

    - ./DockerFiles/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d


But I don't know how to continue and in the official documentation I have only seen how to set up current vhost as default virtual host.
Any help? Thanks in advance
EDIT: The solution was:

Get a copy of the current configuration using the web.app. Tab Overview -> export definitions. It will download a json file with current configuration.

In that JSON, add the virtual host you need. For example, in my case the virtual host will be ABCD:
"vhosts":[
   {
      "name":"/"
   },
   {
      "name":"ABCD"
   }
],
"permissions":[
   {
      "user":"guest",
      "vhost":"/",
      "configure":".*",
      "write":".*",
      "read":".*"
   },
   {
      "user":"guest",
      "vhost":"ABCD",
      "configure":".*",
      "write":".*",
      "read":".*"
   }
],


Create a rabbitmq.conf with these three lines:
loopback_users.guest = false
log.console = true
load_definitions  = /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_definitions.json

In docker-compose, set up these two volumes:

./DockerFiles/rabbitmq/plugins.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins
./DockerFiles/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_definitions.json:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq_definitions.json:ro
./DockerFiles/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.conf:/etc/rabbitmq/conf.d/10-defaults.conf




Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266688/how-to-create-a-queue-in-rabbitmq-upon-startup

Yes, @Raphi1, it was helpful. I'm going to edit my question to add the way I was able to do it.
